# Function and method calls in Python

Tags: python

I noticed Python comes with built-in methods such as .upper() or lower() and these two are part of the string object.

```
"a string".upper()
"A STRING".lower()
```

What confuses me is that some functions are not called on an object, for example the function **type**

```
type("a string")
```

So in this case, is "type" considered a method or just a stand-alone function which is built into the language?

Comment: `type()` is not specific to a type, it is a function that can handle *any of Python's objects*.

Comment: `type` might not be the best example, since `type(type)` show's that type's type is `<class 'type'>`, rather than something like "function" or "method". Maybe look at `len` or `max` when trying to puzzle out the behavior of built-in functions.

Comment: I think, this is the answer you are looking for http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm

Comment: The distinction here is that `type` is a *type*, and types are also callable.